# Question Deletion Etiquette

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, etiquette

When is it alright to delete your own question? I recently posted a question in which I showed correct working code, but it was not working for me. Later I realized that the problem was in a completely different part of my code and the solution was completely irrelevant to the original question.

I deleted the question even though people provided JSFiddles and explanations to why the code may fail in the comments but no answers. Should I have not deleted the question even if I got feedback? What is a similar scenario in which I should not be deleting my own question?

Comment: If you had no answers, its probably alright (especially because you know the problem was entirely elsewhere).

Comment: Great good to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fundamental principle is fairly straightforward: We want combinations of questions and answers that **provide value** to other site visitors. So content that can be helpful to future readers (and that is on topic for the site, of course) should stand. If there is no value, it can be deleted.

Just from the description of your scenario, and without seeing the actual question, it sounds like it can be deleted. Particularly if the problem you were describing was not in the code you posted, I don't think it will be useful to anybody. And you're saying that it has no answer.

Cases where you should not delete your questions: Well, obviously if it's a good question, you should not delete it. Also, if it has answers with valuable content, it becomes much more problematic. You will not even have permission to delete your question anymore if it has an upvoted answer, or more than one answer ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions)).

Comment: I didn't even know you couldn't delete your own post if it had an upvote. I will keep this things in mind, thanks.

Comment: @VladBardalez You can't delete your question if it has an upvoted **answer**. I looked up the details, and edited my post.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.