# Should I delete my own post if the answer was very obvious?

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions

I'm pretty new to programming and StackExchange and I have written a few posts were admittedly silly. The latest one had such an obvious answer that I feel like I should just delete my post all-together.

**My Question:**

In this situation should I just delete my post or leave it?

**edit:**
original post deleted, but this question still stands.

In my original post I wanted to know, more or less how to use @Html.raw()... the answer: "casing matters". Or **r**aw should be **R**aw.

Comment: Read @Aizen's comment on your post.

Comment: I did. I'm waiting for input here before I decide what to do. Tentatively my plan is to just wait for an answer to my post in question and if no one posts one in two days, I'll post one myself and give the proper credit.

Comment: that's good enough.

Comment: Well, with the original question deleted, and without a link to it, now this question does not have much value anymore. Without seeing the question, it's hard to tell how obvious it really was. Easy questions are ok as long as they are not duplicates, and might help somebody else with the same problem.

Comment: It was marked as a duplicate so I deleted it, I'll update my post to help clarify

Comment: There was a somewhat similar question recently. The scenario was not quite the same, but it was also about when to delete questions: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291363/question-deletion-etiquette.

Comment: @RetoKoradi I think the link you just posted resolve my question, they are close enough to mark this as a duplicate. Voted to close.

Comment: There's a close-reason called *This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**.*. In my opinion mixing up `raw` and `Raw` falls well within that so it should at the very least have been closed.

Comment: Think of it this way, though, do we really need to keep around questions that have sprung out from misspelling a method name? That's not going to scale very well at all if we're going to have one for every method on every API in every tag :)

Comment: I agree, I just want to be aware of a general line in the sand where we're expected to keep and expected to delete.