# When should someone remove their own question?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know what is the correct way to measure if a question is still relevant even if it doesn't have votes, or if it is too irrelevant or specific for the community.

I asked a question and it received comments, but at some point I started to think that the question was irrelevant to the community and too specific, so I was thinking about erasing it. That is why:

- Should a question with comments or answers never be erased?
- Or should it be asked to the moderator to determine if the question is relevant?

PS. In my case this is the question that I was talking about:

[Error Docker deployment in Amazon EC2 - Docker container quit unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30077465/error-docker-deployment-in-amazon-ec2-docker-container-quit-unexpectedly)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291363/question-deletion-etiquette.

Answer (score 22):

[The system has a process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) for automatically deleting questions which don't garner any attention.  I wouldn't explicitly encourage someone to delete a question in this state, as that may hurt you more in the long run (with the question ban threshold and all).

Right now, that question may not be gaining anyone's attention, but I think that it'd be alright if you added the resolution in as an answer.

I don't see how it's not relevant to the community; Docker is an up and coming service now and there are going to be a lot more questions around it.  I say, keep it around.

Comment: Thanks for the advice regarding the question ban, I didn't know that it may be negative to erase a zero score question. Regarding the removal of a question my point of view is that questions related to too specific stack seems slightly difficult to reproduce or too user specific, also considering SO as a huge FAQ coding community

Comment: Just t clarify, the answer should be added as an answer, not an edit to the question...

Comment: Thanks, I am going to change the question and add the edit as an answer.

Answer (score 13):

One of the reasons for closing a question is:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

When a question is closed for the above reason, I think it is an obvious candidate to be deleted by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

A question can be safely deleted if you truly think that it can not help anyone else in the future. This is often the case for extremely specific questions.

However, consider this: **Can your question be edited so it is less specific?** Once you have already found the problem in your code, you can often edit your question with future readers in mind.

- What could cause someone to end up with the same problem as me?
- What keywords would people with an alike problem Google for?

Knowing this, you should be able to figure out what sort of Q&A could help others with this or a similar problem. And while you're at it, you can edit the answer as well to garner to the broader public, so it fits to a more general question. **Make it useful** to future readers.